# How to get current connected COM ports within teraterm macro?

Tags: macros, serial-port, port, teraterm

I'm using macro in teraterm.

I wanna use multiple devices with usb-serial cable and I opened each COM ports and macro.

I test 4 devices.

I send cat command, parse result, show result via messagebox.

When I executed same macro for each terminal, there's some problem.

I couldn't identify which messagebox is belong to specific device.

So, I thought of two ways.

First one is make 4 macros and each script has diffent messagebox position.

Second one is make just one macro and show the name which is the port number of current connected device.

Anyone can show me how to get current connected serial port number?

Thanks in advance.